# The simplest way to pack python3 script with dependencies into exe?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, cross-platform

I've tried to google it up but haven't found the exact thing I need and I got stuck.
I have written a Python3.7 script (that uses some external libraries) on Linux. This is just a single module + dependencies.
I need to pack it, preferably to a single .exe file and send it to a Windows user. The file is to be used on Windows system. The user won't have Python installed nor can I expect them to do a lot of setup work.
What would be the simplest way to pack the code (preferably with a cross-compiling, so that I don't need to use Windows) and minimize the amount of setup the Windows user will have to do?

Comment: Checked out [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/)?

Comment: yes, I have checked both pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe

Comment: So where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: 1. they don't seem to be cross compiling 2. even worse, as I am using --onefile option, the external libraries are unknown to the created file (ImportError)

Comment: Simply creating a Python package and having your Windows user install Python (and then your module) is not an option?

Comment: alas, no... I cannot expect the users to have Python installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Artashes' answer, PyInstaller is in fact currently the best tool to compile Python scripts to exe.

But it is not as simple, most of the time, as he says.
Should you have external files used in your script, for example, there is more work to be provided to get a compilation to work. In the same manner, some third-party modules (such as PyQt5 or sounddevice) require a little more work.

I recommend you read the PyInstaller documentation carefully and make sure to read the part about specfiles. Any time I compile a script to an exe I first make a specfile using PyInstaller. I then fill out the specfile to add all problematic dependencies and external files.

At this step you are rarely done. Most of the time one or more of your imports requires manual adding or modifying of the dist folder in order to make things work (for Qt you need to move the Qt5Core.dll to another folder for example).

#### In other words the general steps are as follow:

- Make a specfile using PyInstaller
- Fill out the specfile
- Try to compile.
  If it works, create a script to automate the compilation. You are done.

#### If not:

- Check to see what's not working (missing dll, files in the wrong place)
- Fix it in the automation script.

#### However

PyInstaller works on all platforms BUT it can only compile for the platform it is launched on. In other words using PyInstaller on Windows will create an exe and doing it on Linux will create a binary. Unfortunately there is only one workaround that I know of: Most people (me included) ressort to virtual machines to compile for specific platforms. If you are on linux, install Virtualbox, install a Windows OS and run PyInstaller from the VM to create an exe.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a file called index.py which is  a calculator program. Your question is how you can convert it to .exe file.

1. go to cmd and type command: `pip install pyinstaller`
2. index.py is in "C:\" so type command:  `cd "C:\"`
3. command: `pyinstaller index.py`

There you can find a folder named dist. In that folder you can find a folder named index . So there is your programs .exe file.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that does not solve my problem. Thanks anyway :)